# PyCharm - Exception while doing svn commit

Tags: svn, pycharm

While doing svn commit I am getting following exception message

> Argument 1 for @NotNull parameter of
>   org/jetbrains/idea/svn/commandLine/SvnLineCommand.writeIdeaConfig2SubversionConfig
>   must not be null

I can still commit when I press enter, but mouse click on commit button not working.

OS : Windows 7
Pycharm : 3.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to [IDEA-112854](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112854):

- either upgrade to 3.1 (or newer -- the fix is available in 134.xxx branch)
- or use full path to command line client in settings as workaround for 3.0.2